# Disappearing polygons when zooming in QGIS 3.0

Tags: polygon, layers, qgis-3, layers-failed-to-draw

I am using QGIS 3.0 and loaded a polygon layer from a shapefile containing more than 300,000 polygons. When zooming in some polygons are not drawn (not the entire layer).
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tested QGIS 3.2, the same problem occurs.

Comment: That could be cause to invalid geometry, did you check that ?

Comment: @J.R , how can I check that out?

Comment: There is a "Check validity" tool in processing

Comment: @J.R Could you please convert your comment to an Answer as you suggestion solved my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could be caused by geometry errors.

QGIS Processing Toolbox offers two tools which help to diagnose and fix geometry errors:

- Use the **Check validity** tool to process data into valid, invalid, and erroneous geometry.
- Use the **Fix geometries** tool to repair erroneous geometry.